# All node modules in package.json are being re-downloaded after small change

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I have a NodeJS container with the following Dockerfile

```
FROM node:6

COPY package.json /tmp/package.json

RUN npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
RUN cd /tmp && npm install
RUN mkdir -p /app && cp -a /tmp/node_modules /app/

WORKDIR /app

CMD npm run dev

EXPOSE 80
```

The node modules aren't being re-installed if `package.json` isn't modified whenever I run `docker-compose build`, which is good. However, if I add one more dependency to `package.json`, it seems that all my dependencies are being re-downloaded from NPM, which wastes a lot of time. Is this behaviour intended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the design of the layer caching. When you run the same command with the same inputs as before, Docker finds a layer where you started from the same parent and ran the same command, and is able to reuse that layer. When your input changes (from the COPY command changing its input), the cache becomes invalid and it goes back to building on top of a fresh node:6 image. From that image, none of your previously downloaded files are available.